# Multiple negative expression in if statement is not working in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to testing a folder for ownership, directory & writable in the below if statement which is working as anticipated in bash script

```
if [ -O ./testDir  -a  -d ./testDir  -a -w ./testDir ]
then
    echo "All is well"
else
    echo "All not ok"|  mail -s "Folder Issue" -r "xyz<xyz@xyz.com>" xyz@xyz.com 

fi
```

however I wanted to replace the above if statement with the below, which is not working; it works well if i test each condition in different if statement

```
if [ !  -O ./testDir  -a ! -d ./testDir  -a ! -w ./testDir ] 
then
    echo "All not ok"|  mail -s "Folder Issue" -r " xyz<xyz@xyz.com>" xyz@cisco.com 

fi
```

Please help in case i have done a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
not( expr1 and expr2 and expr3 )
```

with [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is equal to:

```
(not expr1) or (not expr2) or (not expr3)
```

So you should go with:

```
if [ !  -O ./testDir -o ! -d ./testDir -o ! -w ./testDir ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert ! after if:

```
if ! [ -O ./testDir  -a  -d ./testDir  -a -w ./testDir ]
```